# Output a database and its string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get an error where it states invalid column 'DatabaseSQL' when I try to add a database reference into an OUTPUT statement like below:

```
    OUTPUT  [DatabaseSQL] +'.dbo.Package' 'TableName', 'PackageID', inserted.PackageId, 
    Core.updXMLFragment('StatusID', inserted.StatusID, Deleted.StatusID)
    INTO @OutputList
```

If I remove the `DatabaseSQL` and added it as a string like `OUTPUT 'Database.dbo.Package...,` then it works fine, but I need the statement to actually recognise the database as well as add it as a string, just outputting it as a string alone isn't good enough. Any ideas?

Comment: @lad2025 Apologies, I missed the [] brackets in the SO code. But even if I set it as a variable like `Declare @DatabaseSQL [DatabaseSQL]` and then in the output like you mentioned, still provides the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use: [`DB_NAME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx):

```
OUTPUT  DB_NAME() + '.dbo.Package', 'TableName', 'PackageID' ...
```

---

If you store DB name in variable use:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseSQL SYSNAME = QUOTENAME('name with space');   
OUTPUT  @DatabaseSQL + '.dbo.Package', 'TableName', 'PackageID' ...
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417142)**</kbd>

Comment: Just giving it a test for both methods. Was wondering if I can place database name in DB_NAME()?

Comment: @BruceyBandit `Was wondering if I can place database name in DB_NAME()` Can you elaborate?

Comment: So if I'm on Database1 but I want to refer to Database 2, I call it DB_NAME([Database2]), but found out that doesn't work. Will have a go with the sysname method but will that be clever enough to notice database reference if it is displayed as a string? Example: Lets say I reference the db as [$(database1)] so that it always points to that no matter if the db name changes, then if I use the sysname method, will it recognise the reference if string set to '[$(Database1)]'? or will it just output it as a string?

Comment: `SYSNAME` is the same as `NVARCHAR(128)`. I am not sure I get your point but I think you should store `@DatabaseSQL` a variable (simple text) and set it with correct value (SSIS parameter maybe).

Comment: It has allowed me to publish from visual studio to ssms, so I will just test on ssms to ensure that [$(DatabaseSQL)] in visual studio, appears as [DatabaseSQL] in ssms

Comment: Ok, going to apss my senior colleague to test to see if what it outputs is what he needs, if yes then best answer, thank you and a hug :) Upvote answer for now.